# REST URIs case and payload case

Tags: rest

From what I've read, it's common to use hyphen and underscore as a delimiter for a URI name

```
/some-resources or /some_resources
```

My web apps and backend are in JS and so I use camelCase naming convention. That means for any field queries or request payload. The information will be in a different case than the path URI.

```
/some-resources?someAttribute=something
```

Is this considered a bad design?

I see that IBM does something like this:

```
/some_resources?someAttribute=something
```

Is it worth to convert my REST APIs query attributes and payload to be `kebab-case` and then have a layer in my REST backend to normalise the attributes to `camelCase` so that it can process the information?

Answer (score 1):

There is no real difference in what kind of casing is used, only personal preference. If an API were ALL-CAPS screaming at me I might be biased to think that other things might be wrong with an api... but for the examples you mention, different server-side technologies tend to favor different casing and none are wrong.

But I would slightly prefer to pick whatever is the most popular in my ecosystem.